# Praat and sox information script

Tags: audio, sox, praat

How can I do the following?

1. Sound object is selected
2. save sound object as wav (as a temporary filename)
3. run `sox -i adsda.wav` or `soxi adsda.wav`
4. output to the display the result of `sox -i`
5. delete temporary file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute `sox` by calling the `system` directive, and then capture the output in a temporary file. You can then read this temporary file into Praat with `readFile$()`. Here's an example:

```
infile$ = "sound.wav"
outfile$ = "soxi.out"
sound = Create Sound as pure tone: "tone",
  ... 1, 0, 0.4, 44100, 440, 0.2, 0.01, 0.01
Save as WAV file: infile$

system soxi 'infile$' > 'outfile$'
soxi$ = readFile$(outfile$)
appendInfo: soxi$

deleteFile: infile$
deleteFile: outfile$
removeObject: sound
```

I'm not sure what changes (if any) this would need in Windows, but considering you are using `sox`, that probably is not a problem.

Please note that currently (Praat v.5.4) the `system` directive still uses the old syntax, which uses variable substitution. This will probably change in the future. But this script should remain usable even then.

Comment: Thanks! for some reason im getting a error :                  "Unknown function «readFile$» in formula.
Script line 5 not performed or completed:
« soxi$ = readFile$(outfile$) »
Menu command "Run" not completed."                                   not sure why but i get get the info in the praat. @jja

Comment: That's odd. The unknown function error might be because of an older version of Praat. In that case, you could use `soxi$ < 'outfile$'`, which is the "old" way of doing it. I haven't tried it yet, though. But it seems it is working for you nonetheless, so that's good. :)